# Delete only one event from a series of events with jquery fullcalendar 1.5

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

Say I have an event that repeats every day. Now a user wants to delete Monday's event but leave all the rest. How can I do this? Right now since they all have the same repeating Id it will remove all events. I just want one event to be deleted.

Is there away to delete by something else then Id? Like cannot I use my own properties on the event to delete it?

Comment: Hi how you solve this? Can you provide some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use your own properties. But you need to generate them on the server side when the events are loading.

for example ( i will array as example)

```
{
events: [
    {
        title: 'Event1',   //required
        start: '2011-04-04',    //required
        myUniqueID: '000001' //your UniqueID thats embedded in the event!
        className: 'id000001'    //your UniqueID that appears as a class on DOM and get directly using jquery

    },
    {
        title: 'Event2',
        start: '2011-05-05'
        myUniqueID: '000002' //your UniqueID thats embedded in the event!
        myOtherUnqieID: 'allYearOnly',
        yetAnotherUniqueID: 'userDelete:no',
        myBooleanID: false,   //not enclosed in '' !!
        className: 'id000002'    //your UniqueID that appears as a class on DOM and get directly using jquery
    }
    // etc...
],
color: 'yellow',   // an option for the whole source
textColor: 'black' // an option for the whole source
```

}

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Read about non standard fields

Comment: @ppumkin - I am aware of non standard fields but from what I tried it seems that you cannot use non standard fields to remove an event from the calendar(using the removevents). If you know how plz let me know.

Comment: Hmm.. I think i know what you mean. You are trying to remove the event from the source. using  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/removeEvents/  this function instead of putting the ID just use your unique field. I have never done this- but i think soon i will have to do the similar. But try this maybe?

Comment: @ppumkin - Yes I am trying to remove it from the calendar object. So that when the person clicks view on a event then hits "delete only this instance" as soon as he clicks on that it should disappear from the calendar and should never come back(it is gone from the db). I tried to pass in my own unique field into the removeEvents but it does nothing. I think it uses id. 2 solutions that I have come up so far is. ID is unquie for all events and will never repeat. Then on server side check if it repeats. Of course there is a price that full calendar has no knowledge or events that repeat.

Comment: Second way is maybe on click put a marker on that event and then use jquery to remove it but I am not sure if that would remove it from the internal collection or whatever full calendar is using to store it. Plus it is more to keep track off. For now I gone with the first way but always looking for better ways.

Comment: Yea - but the question is where is the feed comming from? Maybe on click you have to send the custom parameter to your ajaxDelete.aspx/php; process the request server side; and reload the source... ?

Comment: @ppumkin - Well I don't want to refresh the whole calendar because one event was deleted.

Comment: Ok - well in that case you can just hide the element using jquery  for example. after adding ClassName into your source id000001 just do $('.id000001').hide() with the on click event. And... you can attach an ajax call to remove it on your server-- but no refresh will occur- and anybody that loads its after will not see it any more if thats what you need? :D

Answer (score 1):

If you set the id attribute to the events (not myUniqueId which is a custom attribute) then you can remove one or more events with such id by using:

```
.fullCalendar("removeEvents", "your_event_id_here")
```

Comment: You don't have to set id. See my solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you have all your id's set use Izet idea.

But when you do NOT have id's in your event do it like this (this work also when you have id's set):

```
eventClick: function(event){
   $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id);
}
```

I've cleared why issue occures in:
[How do I delete this event from FullCalendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649357/how-do-i-delete-this-event-from-fullcalendar/14898194#14898194)

Answer (score 0):

I created a full specific solution for this answer which is happen to be very simple. The secret is to use a custom property (in my case excludedDate) that includes the date to be excluded from the daily concurrent event.
Then, in the eventRender function just return false when reaching this date.

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

    var theDate = event.start
    var excludedDate = event.excludedDate;
    var excludedTomorrrow = new Date(excludedDate);
     //if the date is in between August 29th at 00:00 and August 30th at 00:00 DO NOT RENDER
    if( theDate >= excludedDate && theDate < excludedTomorrrow.setDate(excludedTomorrrow.getDate() + 1) ) {
        return false;
    }
    }
```

Go to the [working demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alelase/gz6mcon1/)