# How to connect full calendar v 1.5.3 with MS SQL Server using asp.net C#/VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ado.net, fullcalendar

I have successfully connected FullCalendar v1.4.2 with sql server using asp.net webforms and vb.net. I want to update to v1.5.3, but the original integration code no longer works and I can't see how to fix it.

Secondly, I would like help adding drag and drop features so that I update the database on drag/drop from asp.net, but I'm not sure where to start for that.

The code I had that worked for v 1.4.2 is as follows:

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev, next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay'
                },
                events: "Calendar.asmx/EventList"
            });

        });
</script>
```

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Web.UI.Page


<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class Calendar
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function EventList(ByVal startDate As String, ByVal endDate As String) As String
        ' List to hold events
        Dim events As List(Of CalendarDTO) = New List(Of CalendarDTO)()

        Dim WebConfigConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("FresheyeTimeTrackerConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM CORE_PROJECT"
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(WebConfigConnection)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds)
        'If startDate > ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now) Then
        'GoTo x
        'End If
        Dim starting As DateTime = FromUnixTimespan(startDate)
        ' Loop through events to be added
        For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("ProjectDeliveryDate").ToString()) Then


            Else

                ' Create a new event and start to populate
                Dim value As CalendarDTO = New CalendarDTO()
                ' Date is required to be in a unix format
                value.StartDate = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Parse(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("ProjectAddedDate").ToString))
                value.id = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("ProjectID").ToString()
                value.title = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("ProjectTitle").ToString()
                value.EndDate = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Parse(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("ProjectDeliveryDate").ToString))
                events.Add(value)

            End If

        Next
        ' Serialize the return value so it can be decoded in java.

x:

        Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
        Return js.Serialize(events)
    End Function

    Private Function ToUnixTimespan(ByVal d As DateTime) As Int64
        Dim time As New TimeSpan()
        time = d.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))

        Return CType(Math.Truncate(time.TotalSeconds), Int64)
    End Function

    Private Function FromUnixTimespan(ByVal s As String) As DateTime
        Dim time As DateTime = New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
        Return time.AddSeconds(s)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: @Brian - wasn't me, but I can give several reasons why one might: No sentences in the prose. Code formatting broke the syntax highlighter. Tagged c# for vb.net-specific question. A bunch of extra and unnecessary code included with the question. Thankfully, I can edit to fix most of that :)

Comment: I placed a c# tag because i wanted a solution for this in either C# or VB language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also struggling with this... It looks like we have borrowed code from similar places...

In your code above you do not seem to be converting startDate and endDate back to start and end. Were you doing this in FullCalendar.js?

Basically I have much the same as yours except before Returning events I do a replace so that the string sent back contains start and end instead of startDate and EndDate.

My code seems to work OK in Chrome but not in IE.

As for updating Db... I'm looking at a couple of answers posted at....

[FullCalendar, how do I allow users to edit/delete events and remove them from the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488153/fullcalendar-how-do-i-allow-users-to-edit-delete-events-and-remove-them-from-th)

Comment: i don't know how to modify the function of FullCalendar.js to change start and end to startDate and end Date. I just downloaded a sample code which was for v1.4 
i used that code to connect to database and it worked fine
but when i used that same code for v1.5.3 it didn't work
is v1.5.3 working for you on chrome ?
can you please provide me that code ?
thanks!

Comment: OK, not sure where you got your code from but I modified the code from [link](http://jake1164.blogspot.com/2011/02/full-calendar-1-410.html). Note that there is a replace js.Serialize(events).Replace("StartDate", "start").Replace("EndDate", "end") which makes sure that the json feed has the correct params for fullCalendar which will be expecting start and end and not startDate and endDate. Next thing is the mods to fullCalendar.js. If you got the file from the above mentioned blog then it has been modified from A Shaw's original. The blog mentions the changed. You need to make similar in 1.5.3

Comment: Continuing... The blog mentions two changes made to 1.4.10 but for 1.5.3 I made just the one change @line 43 and 44 changing the startParam to be startDate and endParam to be endDate. The reason for this is that in VB end is a reserved word. The second change to set the type from GET to POST is now an option in 1.5.3 so you don't need to alter the js. Just include it as one of the options when specifying your sources  ie url : 'yourwebservice.asmx', type : 'POST'

Comment: Let me know if you get it working with IE... like I said, my version works with Chrome but not IE.
Also I've added extra features which change the month view. My calendar is used to display Overtime claims and our claims are based from the 24th of each month. So my calendar start date is the 24th to the 23rd of the following month i.e this months claims run from 24th Feb to 23rd Mar. At the same time the title will display 'Claim Month: March 2012' instead of Febuary 2012.